# How to fix `ParserError: Expected ',' but got '=>'`?

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    uint public totalSupply =  50000000 * 10 ** 18;
    string public name = "DegenarateApe";
    string public symbol = "OOAHOOAH";
    uint public decimals = 18;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);

    constructor() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance to low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
    require(balanceOf(from) => value, 'balance to low');
    require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance to low');
    balances[to] += value;
    balances[from] -= value;
    emit Transfer(from, to, value);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem ??? Why are u writing your own erc20 while you can use the already audits contracts from openZeppelin???

Comment: Basically im trying to learn and while compiling in remix its getting error

ParserError: Expected ',' but got '=>'
--> DegenrateApe.sol:37:29:
|
37 | require(balanceOf(from) => value, 'balance to low');
| ^^

im sure theres more tho

Comment: Replace „=>“ with “ >=„ in transferFrom function